# python pyplot legend adjust (location, size)

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I am trying to change location of plot legend. Below what I've got for now.

```
var_list=powiaty_cols[powiaty_cols.str.contains("apart_bel_40")]
for var in var_list:
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25, 25))
    ax = plt.gca()
    powiaty.plot(column=var,cmap='Reds', categorical=True, 
             legend=True, ax=ax,edgecolor='black')
    ax.legend(loc='best')
```

This code is plotting figure but without legend. I've received errors as follows:

```
No handles with labels found to put in legend.
No handles with labels found to put in legend.
No handles with labels found to put in legend.
No handles with labels found to put in legend.
```

But without part 'ax.legend(loc='best')' I can get my plot but legend is in upper left corner. Plotted column is filled with integer from 1 to 5. Similar issue is when I'm trying to change size of legend.

Could maybe somebody help in this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `powiaty` is, but my guess is that you need to get the `Axes` object back so you can continue modifying it. Try:

```
ax = powiaty.plot(column=var, cmap='Reds', categorical=True, 
                  legend=True, ax=ax, edgecolor='black'
                 )
```

Comment: sorry, this is geopandas dataframe

Comment: Ah okay, so then I think adding the `ax = ...` will work.

Comment: Ok. I found such kind of legend assingment: leg = ax.get_legend(),
    leg.set_bbox_to_anchor((0., 0.1, 0.2, 0.2)). But now I have to increase markers. Any Ideas?

Comment: Increase the size of markers? You can pass `markersize` kwarg to the `powiaty.plot()` call.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked:

```
leg = ax.get_legend()
leg.set_bbox_to_anchor((0., 0.1, 0.2, 0.2))
```